# Desktop PC boots to black screen after ASUS BIOS update

Tags: windows-10, bios, asus-laptop, black-screen-of-death

I tried to update my ASUS motherboard's BIOS just now, but after the installation reached 100% on the update screen, the PC restarted and then simply hung indefinitely on a black screen with no response from the PC whatsoever after a long period of time. The PC wouldn't even POST.

*(Was solved by myself; possible solution is below)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around Google, I came upon a post where somebody experienced a similar issue and managed to fix it by simply doing the following:

1. Force the PC to shut down
2. Unplug the power cord from the PSU for 20-30 seconds; enough so that there's no dormant power left over
3. For good measure, if your motherboard/CPU has embedded graphics, temporarily connect your monitor to that instead of your GPU
4. Plug the power cord back in and then boot the system

---

Some notes:

- This is strictly for desktop PCs (not laptops). If you're on a laptop,
  you might need to disconnect both the power adapter *and* the battery
  to completely shut it down
- If your system was *not* bricked because of the BIOS update, you should see a
  message on the screen stating that the BIOS update is resuming, and
  that you should not cut the power to the PC
- If the BIOS update was successful, your PC will restart again to a
  vanilla POST screen (not the splash screen) and you will need to
  press F1 here and to set everything in the BIOS back to your own
  preferences again
- From what I can tell, the BIOS update *did* succeed after the
  flash in the BIOS, but the installation simply glitched out and
  failed to complete the remaining steps after restarting

---

Some things I should've done before I updated my BIOS:

- Saved a copy of my BIOS configurations to a .CMO file in a USB drive
- Reset my BIOS settings to default before the update

Answer (score 0):

I updated my BIOS as a last resort to fixing my system reserved ram. I ended up getting the infinite black screen. I followed the steps above, shutting down my PC, unplugging my PSU, taking the battery from MOBO, and changed the display ports to MOBO. It didn't quite work yet still left with this black screen death. I repeated those steps one more time but removed my ram and changed them to dimm slots 2 and 4 instead of 1 and 3. For some reason it fixed everything. Now I have all my ram minus 566MB reserved.

Answer (score 0):

My Asus Vivobook notebook was dead, after successful bios update. I tried EVERY possible solution I could find online. In the end, I replaced my RAM card with an other one ONLY for the first boot. BIOS was working perfectly after that. I used again my previous RAM and everything was fine.

Answer (score -3):

{SOLVED} Black screen of death after BIOS update – ASUS X570E Gaming 
{SOLVED} BIOS update after overclocking (OC) – No POST – DRAM LED on
After a lot of grief I was able to solve this problem. I have never built a PC before and I was really stressed when I faced this problem. I know how it feels. This is a noob PC builder post.

Hardware: Mobo=Asus x570E Gaming, CPU= Ryzen 3900x, GPU=ASUS 2070S, RAM=G Skill Trident Z, PSU=Corsair RM650x.

Situation: I was able to install Windows and drivers, but I overclocked my RAM in BIOS from default 2133 MHz to 3200 MHz. Then I used the EZ Flash 3 update to update the BIOS. The BIOS reached 100% but it was taking a lot of time so I went to do some stuff. After returning, no POST, black screen of death, DRAM LED is on. I sent my motherboard for replacement under warranty and they said product is not faulty and returned me the same motherboard.

1. Despite a lot of information on internet, don’t immediately believe it’s a motherboard issue. Do the following steps before you tear down your PC.
2. First follow the troubleshooting steps given by ASUS. Follow this link : https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042678/
3. I tried plugging DisplayPort into multiple inputs on my GPU.
4. Some people have reported that they solved this issue by removing the power cord from PSU, pressing the switch on button to release the current/power from system, and then replugging the PSU and turning on after 1-2 minutes.
5. If the above steps doesn’t solve the DRAM led on problem, then try to clear the CMOS memory. You can find YouTube videos to do that since every motherboard is made differently. Follow the link below for a general idea:
   https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1040820/
6. If even all the above steps doesn’t solve your problem – a pretty good chance that they haven’t because none of it worked for me – try downgrading the BIOS. You can do that by using the BIOS flashback button at the back I/O panel on ASUS motherboards.

   IMPORTANT: This is where you can confirm there’s nothing wrong with your motherboard.

   1. The first sign that your motherboard is fine is that everything turns on. All the LEDs work. There's nothing wrong with RAM slots or RAM correctly in place otherwise there would be no RGB on your RAM. Having RGB components is a good idea. Your ASUS motherboard gives you the Q-codes as well.
   2. When you downgrade the BIOS using flashback button, follow the steps mentioned in the manual for your motherboard. If your motherboard is working properly, you will notice that when BIOS installation starts, your BIOS flashback LED will blink green for a few minutes and then turn off.
7. This is the last step which solved my problem. Check your PSU-the 24 pin cable going into your mobo. Follow the link below to learn how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr70VyoACPg
   when I tested my PSU, I could not detect any 12V or 3V outputs from my 24-pin cable plugged into mobo. I returned the PSU under warranty, got a new PSU and everything works perfectly.

ADVICE:

1. It helps if you have another PC with parts that you can test your brand new components on.
   2.If none of the 7 steps above help you, it still might be RAM issue – don’t tear down the PC just yet.
2. If it's not the RAM, and you finally have to tear down the PC, please be careful when you detach CPU cooler fan from CPU. I was using the stock wraith prism fan that came with Ryzen CPU. My PC was cold and when I tried to take the fan off, the CPU came out of its socket! I almost died! I was lucky, and none of the CPU pins were damaged. To remove the fan, any type of fan, from a cold CPU, I would recommend using a hair dryer to heat the thermal paste. The fan came off pretty easily when I did that.

My thoughts – from what I have read online, AMD CPUs on X570 motherboards can use a lot of power, especially when over clocking. I believe that updating BIOS after clocking could have caused an overvoltage or something that just damaged my 24-pin motherboard connector. It doesn't make sense though, because Corsair RM650x comes with over-voltage and over current protection. The only other thing I can think of is that Corsair RM650x cable are very rigid and inflexible. Cable management is hard so maybe I damaged the cable that way. Again *it doesn't make sense* because I used my PC for good 3-4 hours installing Windows, drivers and all before updating BIOS.

I can’t do it, but if you’re reading this post go for a PSU that comes with 8+4 pins CPU cable connector. This will at least give you peace of mind that if in the future that if you want to overclock you can do it. Corsair RM650x PSU comes with only an 8-pin CPU connector.